# Build Kaa from source code - Kaa Client (Java Desktop) FAILURE

Tags: kaa

OS:Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop amd64

JDK version:jdk1.8.0_151

maven version:Apache Maven 3.5.2

I downloaded kaa source code from github, and follow the guide run the command as follow：
    mvn -P compile-gwt,mongo-dao,mariadb-dao clean install verify

However, it cannot finish building,and throw an error as follow:

```
 Results :

 Failed tests: 
 PingConnectivityCheckerTest.checkConnectivityToSomeHostTest:33 null
```

Tests run: 21, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Reactor Summary:

[INFO] Kaa ................................................ SUCCESS [02:06 min]

[INFO] Kaa Avro Generator ................................. SUCCESS [10:39 min]

[INFO] Kaa Common ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.528 s]

[INFO] Kaa Endpoint - Server Shared ....................... SUCCESS [02:08 min]

[INFO] Kaa Core ........................................... SUCCESS [ 20.939 s]

[INFO] Kaa Client ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.538 s]

[INFO] Kaa Client (Multi) ................................. SUCCESS [  0.495 s]

[INFO] Kaa Client (Java Core) ............................. SUCCESS [01:31 min]

[INFO] Kaa Client (Java Desktop) .......................... FAILURE [01:07 min]

[INFO] Kaa Client (Java Android) .......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Kaa Client (C++) ................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Kaa TCP (C) ........................................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Kaa Client (C) ..................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Kaa Client (Objective-C) ........................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Kaa Server components .............................. SKIPPED

...

...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 18:03 min

[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-17T12:19:55+08:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 70M/1170M

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project client-java-desktop: There are test failures.
[ERROR]

[ERROR] Please refer to /root/kaa/client/client-multi/client-java-desktop/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

[ERROR]

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :client-java-desktop

I dont know why  Java Desktop would be failure

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

build using mvn -DskipTests -P compile-gwt,mongo-dao,mariadb-dao clean install verify

in eclipse right -click on kaa-node => run=> run configurations=> 
in the goal put **-P compile-gwt,mongo-dao,mariadb-dao clean install verify**
and below check **skip Test**.
and run.